# Object Spread and Rest Operators in Typescript 2.1 - error at usage attempt

Tags: angular, typescript2.0

Typescript 2.1.6

I have the foolowing:

#### registrant.reducers.ts

```
const registration_reducers = { 
languageData: languageDataReducer,
  languageUi: languageUiReducer}
```

#### app.reducers.ts

```
import { registration_reducers } from '../registration/+registrant/registrant.reducers'

const reducers = {...registration_reducers}
```

Webstorm displays no errors. However, compilation fails with the following message:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/store/app.reducer.ts
Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at _getContentOfKeyLiteral (J:\workspace\angular2\ts\epimss\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:9:13)
    at node.properties.some.prop (J:\workspace\angular2\ts\epimss\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:205:56)
    at Array.some (native)
    at refactor.findAstNodes.filter (J:\workspace\angular2\ts\epimss\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:205:43)
    at Array.filter (native)
    at _removeModuleId (J:\workspace\angular2\ts\epimss\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:205:10)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (J:\workspace\angular2\ts\epimss\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:301:33)
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 21:0-46
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/ ./src/main.ts
```

Reading the docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html>Object Spread and Rest suggest that this should work.

What am I doing wrong. 
Cheers

Comment: no where in your code the **kind** property is there. So how is it possible to figure out your mistake? Update your post

Comment: I don't have a 'kind' property anywhere in my code. That is the difficult part. I thought it was somewhere in angular2 or typescript. The error is not the most helpful.

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Comment: no. Never use it.

Comment: I didnt get you. Be clear

Comment: I am not available on Team Viewer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136657/discussion-between-aravind-and-st-clair-clarke).

Comment: @AngularFrance Yes, it works with an explicit list.

Comment: Are you positive you're using Typescript 2.1.6? You seem to be using angular-cli. In my angular-cli (1.0.0-beta.32.3) I see that it uses Typescript 2.0.10.

Comment: @AngularFrance I am positive. I updated it to use the features. The following line is take from my package.json file `"typescript": "^2.1.6",` Unless somehow the cli uses the typescript it bundles without us knowing.

Answer (score 0):

If this *is* in fact related to the Spread operator:

[Angular 2.4.2 added support for TypeScript 2.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-21), in which case you need to make sure that you are running that first (check your `package.json`).

I would also suggest doing a fresh/clean install of your `node_modules`.